# bash regexp that match to character sequence

Tags: bash

I am writing a bash script that receives `<task>` ID strings as a parameter and then executes the specified tasks. At the end of the execution, it must show the total execution time. The code must be flexible, and easy to add new conditions.

Usage: `build.sh <task><task><task>...`

The task id is a little bit tricky:

- if it is only a character [a-z] then it represents all subtasks of the given task
- if it is a character + a number, it represents only the specific subtask

Let me give you some examples:

- `build.sh a1a2`: execute tasks of `a1` and `a2`, but not `a3`
- `build.sh a`: execute all tasks starts with char `a` (all subtasks of `a`)
- `build.sh a1b`: run only task `a1` and all subtasks of `b`
- `build.sh a1b3`: run only task `a1` and `b3`
- `build.sh ab`: run all subtasks of `a` and `b`
- `build.sh *`: run all tasks defined is the build script (all subtasks), like `a` + `b` + `c`

The execution order of the tasks is pre-defined, so actually `b1a1` will execute `a1b1`.

This is my bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash -ue

# show help
function show_help() {
    if [ "$1" -eq 0 ]; then
        printf "..."
        exit 0
    fi
}

# does the build
function build {
    local title dir
    title="$1"
    dir="$2"
    printf "\n%b> building '%s'...%b\n" "$COLOR_YELLOW" "$title" "$COLOR_DEFAULT"
    cd "$WORKSPACE/../$dir"
    ./build.sh
    cd "$WORKSPACE"
}

# group A build
function build_group_a {
    if [[ "$1" == *a1* ]]; then build "task A.1" "base/xxx"; fi
    if [[ "$1" == *a2* ]]; then build "task A.2" "base/yyy"; fi
    if [[ "$1" =~ $(getRegexp a) ]]; then
      build "task A.1" "base/xxx"
      build "task A.2" "base/yyy"
    fi
}

# group B build
function build_group_b {
   # same with 'build_group_a' only conditions are different
}

# REGEXP THAT DOES NOT WORK PROPERLY
function getRegexp() {
    printf ".*%s[a-z].*" "$1"
}


show_help "$#"
START_TIME=$(date +%s)

# 'all' works but '*' not
if [[ "$1" == all ]]; then
    build_group_a a
    build_group_b b
else
    build_group_a "$1"
    build_group_b "$2"
fi

ELAPSED=$(($(date +%s) - START_TIME))
printf "build time: %s\n" "$(date -d@$ELAPSED -u +%H\ hour\ %M\ day\ %S\ sec)"
```

Everything works fine, tasks are executed properly in order but if I use `build.sh a` then nothing is executed. If I use `build.sh ab`, only tasks `a` are executed. I do not know why. It seems that the last task-ID is not processed by my regexp.

Another issue is that if I say `build.sh aa1` then all tasks for `a` are executed but task `a1` twice. Task `a1` must only be executed once when `a` is called.

That could be great if you can guide me on how to fix the problem in my regular expression.

Comment: This might help: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Comment: `a` fails because `.*a[a-z].*` has minimum length 2. `ab` doesn't match `.*b[a-z].*` so `b` doesn't run.

Comment: you can stop `a` and `a1`/`a2` running by changing (if a1, if a2, if a) to (if a else ( if a1, if a2 ))

Comment: better printf for regex might be `%s([^0-9]|$)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the regex part, you can try this :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

input="$1"
pattern='(\*|[[:alpha:]][[:digit:]]?)'
while [[ $input =~ $pattern ]]; do
    echo "Argument passed : ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
    input="${input:${#BASH_REMATCH[0]}}" # next iteration
done
```

test with :

```
bash build.sh a1b
bash build.sh "*"
```

Comment: Okay, this is the reason why the asterisk was not working for me. It must be put between brackets. Interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for your comments. Based on your help I was able to fix the issue.
In the final version I use a little bit different approach for the regexp than before.
And in the meanwhile I simplified everything.

This is the code with the regexp:

```
#!/bin/bash -ue

function build {
    local arg id title dir group regexp
    arg=$(printf "%sz" "$1")
    id="$2"; title="$3"; dir="$4"; group=${id:0:1}
    regexp=$(printf "(0|%s|%s[a-z])" "$id" "$group")
    if [[ "$arg" =~ $regexp ]]; then
        printf "%b> building '%s'...%b\n" "$COLOR_YELLOW" "$title" "$COLOR_DEFAULT"
        cd "$WORKSPACE/.../$dir"
        ./build.sh
        cd "$WORKSPACE"
    fi
}

function show_help() {
    if [ "$1" -eq 0 ]; then
        printf "..."
        exit 0
    fi
}

...
show_help "$#"
START_TIME=$(date +%s)

build "$1" "a1" "task A.1" "aa/xxx"
build "$1" "a2" "task A.2" "aa/yyy"
build "$1" "b1" "task B.1" "bb/vvv"
build "$1" "b2" "task B.2" "cc/www"

ELAPSED=$(($(date +%s) - START_TIME))
printf "build time: %s\n\n" "$(date -d@$ELAPSED -u +%H\ hour\ %M\ day\ %S\ sec)"
```

This works like a charm and I think that it is enough simple.

I use `0` to run all of the tasks because unfortunately, the asterisk(`*`) was not working for me in my regexp.
Another trick that I had to do is to add an extra character (in my case it is an `z`) at the end of the user input. That was necessary, otherwise, the last command won't be executed.